# Set link to title jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello i already paid for a template and they can`t help me with this question, look at this template [Demo template](http://demo.joinwebs.com/classiera/allure/)

If you want to open an ad they did to open only by clicking on title or view ad.
What i want is when user click on image to open the ad so basically to take the href from title and put it for entire div.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the templates of that view file and add the relevant code to that image where it will open the same as clicking on title.

Comment: Hi, thank you for response i know is not an example post but i really need some help i don`t know ReduxFramework.

Comment: Yes there are redux framework templates are there which you need to modify as per your requirements ..